# Entity-Framework Model First - Table names

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I'm just starting with entity-framework and VisualStudio 2015 RC.
The intention is to design the data model and generate the SQL Server database.

I did it and I have a question: the table names have "Set" postfix. I mean that `Company` entity is created as `CompanySet` table.

Is this a new convention?

I have been watching tutorials with previous versions of EF/VS and I didn't see this postfix when naming tables.

Thanks.

FJ

Comment: Welcome to SO! :) Looks like you are using EF:Code First (you should add it to tags) -- Short answer is, you can add `[Table("Company")]` attribute to your poco classes to rename it. Btw, do you have Company as `public Set<Company>CompanySet {get;set;}` or `public Set<Company>Company {get;set;}` on your Context? I have no idea about conventions changes, so i dont want to post whole "answer".

Comment: I started with empty model, adding entities and then generating the database from them. I got the "...Set" name in table names.

I can change the EntitySet name from "CompanySet" to "Company" and I suppose it will create tables with this name but... is this correct?

Comment: Ou, in that case my bad - its NOT Code First, i am really sorry to confuse you. (btw i think yes, i am pretty sure thats correct - but i am much more familiar with Code First)